# Telerik Radgrid filtrar sin tener en cuenta los acentos

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un Radgrid de Telerik en el que quiero hacer búsquedas (filtrar) y que no tenga en cuenta los acentos, es decir, si tengo como datos "Camión" y "Camion", que al escribir en el filtro "Camion" me aparezcan los dos resultados y viceversa.
   Hay alguna propiedad ya incluida en el propio control que permita hacer esto?.

Gracias.

Comment: No he utilizado ese control, pero dudo que lo tenga por defecto. Yo lo solucionaría creando una columna oculta, con los mismo valores de la columna problematica pero eliminando los caracteres problematicos, y filtraria por esa columna oculta.

Comment: Si estas filtrando del lado del servidor con Entityframework es posible que la base de datos tenga un set de caracteres sensible a acentos, esta el valor por defecto de SQL server, Oracle lo he usado poco pero me paso que era sensible ha acentos y lo pude arreglar con un trigger cuando el usuario del dase de datos inicia sesión. Para SQL server la única forma que pude solucionarlo fue reconstruyendo la base de datos para cambiar el Set de caracteres por defecto, no digo que sea la única manera, pero en mi caso la BD no estaba todavía en producción.

Comment: este link tambien podria servirte http://www.telerik.com/forums/accent-insensitive-filtering-filtering-on-a-different-column

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas. Ya me temía que no iba a ser tan fácil :-( Byron, el link que comentas ya lo vi, pero el caso es que tengo muchisimos grids en la aplicación y con muchas columnas problemáticas. Buscaba una manera rápida y fácil de hacerlo. Pero me temo que no va a poder ser.

Answer (score 1):

No existe algo nativo del control, pero programando en los eventos pueda que resuelvas tu problema. Estos son los pasos:

1. En el evento del radgrid NeedDataSource, se eliminan los acentos con el siguiente método y se crea una copia oculta sin acentos:

   ```
   public static string RemoveDiacritics(string s)  
   {  
       string normalizedString = s.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);  
       StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();  

       for (int i = 0; i < normalizedString.Length; i++)  
       {  
           char c = normalizedString[i];  
           if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)  
           {  
               stringBuilder.Append(c);  
           }  
       }  
       return stringBuilder.ToString();  
   }
   ```
2. En el evento `itemCommand` del `radgrid`, se chequea si la columna tiene acentos, por ejemplo `[RaisonSociale]`, si es así, se toma la columna oculta que no tiene acentos `[RaisonSocialeFiltre]`:

   ```
   protected void RadGridClients_ItemCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)  
   {  
       if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.FilterCommandName)  
       {  
           Pair laPaire = (Pair)e.CommandArgument;  
           if (string.Compare((string)laPaire.Second, "RaisonSociale") == 0)  
           {  
               e.Canceled = true;  

               TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)((GridFilteringItem)e.Item)["RaisonSociale"].Controls[0];  
               FiltreOriginalClient = txtBox.Text;  

               GridColumn colonneCachee = ((RadGrid)source).MasterTableView.GetColumnSafe("RaisonSocialeFiltre");  
               colonneCachee.CurrentFilterFunction = (GridKnownFunction)(Enum.Parse(typeof(GridKnownFunction), Convert.ToString(laPaire.First, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), true));  
               colonneCachee.CurrentFilterValue = Utilitaire.RemoveDiacritics(txtBox.Text);  
               ((RadGrid)source).Rebind();  

               GridFilteringItem filterItem = ((RadGrid)source).MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.FilteringItem)[0] as GridFilteringItem;  
               filterItem.FireCommandEvent("Filter", new Pair((string)laPaire.First, "RaisonSocialeFiltre"));  
           }  
       }  
   }
   ```
3. Finalmente, en el evento `ItemDataBound`, se devuelve el filtro a su estado original, en esta caso se usa una variable `global` llamada `FiltreOriginalClient`:

   ```
       protected void RadGridClients_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)  
   {  
       // Utilisé pour remettre le filtre dans le textbox filtre en haut de la colonne RaisonSociale  
       if (e.Item.ItemType == GridItemType.FilteringItem)  
       {  
           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox)((GridFilteringItem)e.Item)["RaisonSocialeFiltre"].Controls[0]).Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(FiltreOriginalClient))  
           {  
               ((TextBox)((GridFilteringItem)e.Item)["RaisonSociale"].Controls[0]).Text = FiltreOriginalClient;  
           }  
       }  
   }
   ```

Espero esto te ayude.

Referencia: [ACCENT INSENSITIVE FILTERING - Filtering on a different column](http://www.telerik.com/forums/accent-insensitive-filtering-filtering-on-a-different-column)

Comment: Hola EAFC y bienvenido a SO en español. Te recomiendo que te leas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio y verás que para que una respuesta sea válida en el sitio es importante extraer la información importante de los links a tu respuesta. Piensa que los links pueden dejar de funcionar y eso invalidaría la respuesta :). Un saludo!

Comment: Hola. Muchas gracias por contestar. Sí, finalmente lo solucioné así, encontré el mismo enlace que pones (ACCENT INSENSITIVE FILTERING). El caso es que buscaba alguna manera más directa de hacerlo, ya que con la aplicación que trabajo tiene como 100 grids y cada grid puede tener entre 2 y 4 columnas con este problema. Pero esta es la mejor solución que he encontrado.

Answer (score 0):

la verdad que no existe ninguna propiedad que haga esto en el framework, a lo sumo lo vas a tener que hacerlo de manera manual vos. Ya sea remplazando las vocales de cada consulta antes de realizar la consulta. 
Saludos

Comment: Sí, eso me temo. Gracias por responder.

Answer (score 0):

He tenido este problema desde tiempos inmemorables, y debido a que mis clientes nunca me exigieron esta funcionalidad, nunca me puse a lograr este filtro sin tener en cuenta los acentos.

Recientemente estuve involucrado en un pequeño proyecto en el que dije ¡ya basta!, e implementé esta funcionalidad de la manera más cómoda posible.

El código es compatible con Telerik UI for WinForms 2017 R1 o superior, y Visual Studio 2015 o superior.

Veo que la dificultad se presenta con Telerik y ASP.NET. Espero que la diferencia no sea tan grande respecto a Telerik y WinForms.

Código fuente de la clase ayudante:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using Telerik.WinControls.Data;
using Telerik.WinControls.UI;

namespace MySoftware.Helpers
{
    internal static class RadGridViewHelper
    {
        private class CustomStringFilteringClass
        {
            private RadGridView RadGridView { get; }
            private bool _enabled;
            private ReadOnlyCollection<string> StringColumns { get; }

            public CustomStringFilteringClass(RadGridView radGridView)
            {
                RadGridView = radGridView;
                StringColumns = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(GetStringColumns(radGridView));
            }

            public void Enable()
            {
                if (_enabled) throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't call this method twice");
                _enabled = true;

                RadGridView.EnableCustomFiltering = true;
                RadGridView.CustomFiltering += RadGridViewOnCustomFiltering;
            }

            private void RadGridViewOnCustomFiltering(object sender, GridViewCustomFilteringEventArgs e)
            {
                if (RadGridView.FilterDescriptors.Count == 0) return;

                var row = e.Row;

                foreach (var stringColumn in StringColumns)
                {
                    var filterDescriptors = RadGridView.FilterDescriptors.Where(
                        x => x.PropertyName == stringColumn).ToList();
                    if (filterDescriptors.Count != 1)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    var filterDescriptor = filterDescriptors.First();
                    var cellValue = ((string)row.Cells[stringColumn].Value).ToLowerInvariant();
                    if (filterDescriptor.GetType() == typeof(CompositeFilterDescriptor))
                    {
                        if (!CompositeFilterEvaluateString((CompositeFilterDescriptor)filterDescriptor, cellValue,
                            RadGridView.MasterTemplate.DataView.FilterEvaluate, row))
                        {
                            e.Visible = false;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (!FilterEvaluateString(filterDescriptor, cellValue,
                        RadGridView.MasterTemplate.DataView.FilterEvaluate, row))
                    {
                        e.Visible = false;
                        return;
                    }
                }

                var nonStringFilterDescriptors = RadGridView.FilterDescriptors.Where(
                    x => !StringColumns.Contains(x.PropertyName));
                foreach (var filterDescriptor in nonStringFilterDescriptors)
                {
                    if (!RadGridView.MasterTemplate.DataView.FilterEvaluate(filterDescriptor, row))
                    {
                        e.Visible = false;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

            private static bool CompositeFilterEvaluateString(CompositeFilterDescriptor compositeFilterDescriptor,
            string cellValue, Func<FilterDescriptor, GridViewRowInfo, bool> gridFilterEvaluate, GridViewRowInfo row)
            {
                switch (compositeFilterDescriptor.LogicalOperator)
                {
                    case FilterLogicalOperator.And:
                        if (compositeFilterDescriptor.FilterDescriptors.Any(filterDescriptor =>
                        {
                            if (filterDescriptor.GetType() == typeof(CompositeFilterDescriptor))
                                return !CompositeFilterEvaluateString((CompositeFilterDescriptor)filterDescriptor,
                                    cellValue, gridFilterEvaluate, row);
                            return !FilterEvaluateString(filterDescriptor, cellValue, gridFilterEvaluate, row);
                        }))
                            return false;
                        break;
                    case FilterLogicalOperator.Or:
                        if (compositeFilterDescriptor.FilterDescriptors.All(filterDescriptor =>
                        {
                            if (filterDescriptor.GetType() == typeof(CompositeFilterDescriptor))
                                return !CompositeFilterEvaluateString((CompositeFilterDescriptor)filterDescriptor,
                                    cellValue, gridFilterEvaluate, row);
                            return !FilterEvaluateString(filterDescriptor, cellValue, gridFilterEvaluate, row);
                        }))
                            return false;
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }

            private static bool FilterEvaluateString(FilterDescriptor filterDescriptor, string cellValue,
                Func<FilterDescriptor, GridViewRowInfo, bool> gridFilterEvaluate, GridViewRowInfo row)
            {
                var filterDescriptorValue = ((string) filterDescriptor.Value).ToLowerInvariant();
                switch (filterDescriptor.Operator)
                {
                    case FilterOperator.Contains:
                        if (CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(cellValue, filterDescriptorValue,
                                CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace) == -1)
                            return false;
                        break;
                    case FilterOperator.NotContains:
                        if (CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(cellValue, filterDescriptorValue,
                                CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace) != -1)
                            return false;
                        break;
                    case FilterOperator.StartsWith:
                        if (!CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IsPrefix(cellValue, filterDescriptorValue,
                            CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace))
                            return false;
                        break;
                    case FilterOperator.EndsWith:
                        if (!CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IsSuffix(cellValue, filterDescriptorValue,
                            CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace))
                            return false;
                        break;
                    case FilterOperator.IsEqualTo:
                        if (String.Compare(cellValue, filterDescriptorValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace) != 0)
                            return false;
                        break;
                    case FilterOperator.IsNotEqualTo:
                        if (String.Compare(cellValue, filterDescriptorValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace) == 0)
                            return false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        if (!gridFilterEvaluate.Invoke(filterDescriptor, row))
                            return false;
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }

        private static List<string> GetStringColumns(RadGridView radGridView)
        {
            var retVal = new List<string>();
            foreach (var column in radGridView.Columns)
            {
                if (column.DataType == typeof(string))
                {
                    retVal.Add(column.Name);
                }
            }
            return retVal;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Enables custom string filtering on <paramref name="radGridView"/>. It is case insensitive and
        /// tolerates differences in diacritical marks. For example, in a "equals" comparision, the value
        /// 'ëMúa' is treated as its equal to 'EmÜâ'.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="radGridView">Instance of <see cref="RadGridView"/> in which custom string filtering
        /// will be enabled.</param>
        public static void CustomStringFiltering(RadGridView radGridView)
        {
            var customFiltering = new CustomStringFilteringClass(radGridView);
            customFiltering.Enable();
        }
    }
}
```

Y el uso es muy simple:

`RadGridViewHelper.CustomStringFiltering(radGridView);`

Donde `radGridView` es la instancia de la clase `RadGridView` a la cual se le desea alterar el comportamiento del filtrado de textos.

Es importante que antes de llamar al método `CustomStringFiltering` ya se hayan agregado todas las columnas con sus tipos de datos adecuados a `radGridView`. También es importante no modificar, agregar o eliminar las columnas después de llamar al método `CustomStringFiltering`.

El nuevo comportamiento del filtrado de texto es tal que en una comparación de tipo "Igual a", el valor `ëMúa` es tratado como si fuese igual a `EmÜâ`.

Disculpas por el código fuente en inglés **P:**